# Why do most people consider Green Lantern (2011) a disaster?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

I never read the comic books but I watched the movie and although it wasn't well written or smart, it was at least fun and had a lot of cool visual effects.

It was, at best a *mediocre* movie but everyone on internet says it was a **disaster.**

**Why?**

Comment: http://whatculture.com/film/50-reasons-why-green-lantern-movie-sucks.php/3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Overall Green Lantern was a train wreck of a film. In short, it **sucked.**. But "why?", I hear you ask...

### It was poorly reviewed by the public

The film has achieved just 5.7 on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1133985/) and a 26% on [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/770677993). Although the initial reception (e.g. before seeing it) was generally positive, after seeing it, people failed to recommend the film to their friends.

### It was poorly reviewed by [critics](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1133985/externalreviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt)

Pretty much the most positive professional review I could find comes from the [Examiner](http://www.examiner.com/review/green-lantern-2011-review-fizzles-but-no-pop)

> Now, I did not see this movie in 3D, so I cannot vouch for any
>   difference in the moviegoer experience, but Green Lantern (2011) was
>   mediocre at best. It seems to serve as a stepping stone into future
>   Lantern flicks instead of a wholesome headlining franchise experience.
>   Would I recommend this film to others? Sure, why not…it is the summer
>   after all.

Hardly high praise...

### It was a box office flop

According to [Box Office Mojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=greenlantern.htm), the film cost some $200M to make and has recouped (to date) less than $230M. Although this isn't an actual *loss*, it's considered to be a **crashing disaster** when you take into account the lost opportunity costs (e.g. if you'd made a better film) and the extra marketing and advertising spending that isn't factored into the production costs.

### It killed the franchise

After the film's failure, Warner Bros (and the main cast and crew) [cancelled their plans](http://www.latinospost.com/articles/23991/20130719/green-lantern-sequel-movie-news-update-ryan-reynolds-video.htm) to turn the film in to a film series. Despite the rich mine of potential storylines available from the comic canon, the film is now basically orphaned. In 15-20 years, they may try a reboot, pretending the 2011 film never happened.

Given the comparable recent success of the X-Men film series, Superman film series, Batman film series, etc this single movie failure may have robbed the studio of a franchise worth **billions** of dollars.

Comment: This was also their first failure at making a shared universe ala Marvel.  Angela Bassett's Amanda Waller was going to be the connecting tissue.

Comment: For what it's worth, they're rebooting [in 2020](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Comics'_shared_universe_films#Green_Lantern_.282020.29).

Comment: @Nerrolken - I'm happy to bet a shiny pound coin that they don't. They'll want the current generation of movie-goers to be old enough not to influence the reviews of the new film.

Comment: @Richard Oh yeah, I'm totally willing to agree that the current DCCU plans will collapse in on themselves before GL gets made.  But since we're discussing reboots and the future of GL onscreen, it's worth noting that they've already announced a reboot plan, and GL as a character will probably be in the *Justice League* films (2017 and/or 2019), even before then.

Comment: @Richard But, supporting your argument, it is *the very last* of DC's announced film plans, behind even comparatively-minor characters like Cyborg & Shazam.

Comment: Note that it actually probably was a pretty significant loss in terms of revenue. Keep in mind that the studio only gets about half the box office take (less in foreign markets) and that the budget generally doesn't include distribution costs. As far as I know, films generally need to gross around double their budget to break even for the studio.

Comment: @Richard Sony and Marvel prove that Hollywood has no need for us to forget films before rebooting them: http://www.forbes.com/sites/benjaminmoore/2015/04/29/asa-butterfield-new-spider-man/

Comment: WHY did Green Lantern (2011) suck? Two words: Hector Hammond.

Comment: @Omegacron - The lack of a memorable villain certainly wouldn't help.