# Who is the seventh person in the "Unite the Seven?"

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In the *Justice League* movie marketing, the phrase "Unite the Seven" came up frequently. However, as I count the members that have been confirmed to be appearing, only six come up: Batman, Wonder Woman, Superman, Cyborg, Flash, and Aquaman. Is there a seventh one that I am missing? Am I just being stupid?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We've already seen *six* of the *seven* classic comicbook members of the Justice League; 
Superman (Henry Cavill), Batman (Ben Affleck), Wonder Woman (Gal Gadot), The Flash (Ezra Miller), Cyborg (Ray Fisher) and Aquaman (Jason Momoa).

The one who's missing from the classic lineup is of course **The Green Lantern** who's yet to appear in any recent DCU property and may or may not do so in the finalised cut of the film [given how poorly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/why-do-most-people-consider-green-lantern-2011-a-disaster/87612#87612) the 2011 Green Lantern stand-alone film fared.

[image]

You may wish to note that the Phrase "Unite the Seven" was only used in conjunction with Aquaman, leading to fan theories that the seven may refer to the [seven seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Seas) rather than the seven members of the JLA. Also, the actual phrase seems to have been quietly dropped by the marketing folks at DC and there's been zero (official) activity on the hashtag for nearly a year.

Comment: ^_^ I see you ran into the same sources.

Comment: I don't know if this is official, but I've heard that at least one member of the Green Lantern Corps will appear in the film, albeit in a cameo.

Comment: Apparently, Green Lantern has been indicated to not show up in part 1 (unless they're lying): http://batman-news.com/2016/03/03/green-lantern-justice-league-2/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I think the Justice League film is gonna be a trainwreck. It reeks of studio interference and if the BvS film is anything to go by, it'll have great effects and piss-poor writing.

Comment: As far as I know, the _Green Lantern Corps_ movie is still a go, but not slated to come out until after both parts of _Justice League_. OTOH, the current rumor is that it may have _three_ Earth Lanterns in it, which is a lot of backstory to squeeze in, so I can see them at least introducing the concept in an earlier movie.

Comment: @KutuluMike - I'm going to go out on a limb and bet that it's not going to happen. It's too soon to the 2011 flopbuster and there's no sensible reason for them to tempt fate (on their moderately successful movie franchise) by having the two compared by critics.

Comment: @Valorum "GL may or may not appear in the next film given how poorly the stand alone film fared." - It terrifies me that this is how they make decisions because it shows zero comprehension of their mistakes. And they're fooling themselves if they think BvS was in any way a better movie than the GL film, regardless of what the Box office suggests.

Comment: @DavidH - Unfortunately, the business of making movies is first and foremost a business, and never more so than today.

Comment: @Valorum On an unrelated note, I looked at that 'Seven Seas' Wiki article and was surprised to learn that the historical origins of the idiom are like tied up with the seven classical planets/deities  of ancient times. If that's the case then we've come full circle because originally the Justice League was heavily modeled after the seven primary Olymplic gods

Answer (score 8):

Green Lantern is often listed as the seventh major member.

[image: Seven members]

However, [he has been confirmed to not be in Justice League Part 1](http://batman-news.com/2016/03/03/green-lantern-justice-league-2/).

> “Every beat of the movie is not yet worked out. So there’s the possibility that he may or may not be in Justice League 2,” Roven says. “For now, we felt that we were introducing enough characters that the best possible place we could put Green Lantern is some introduction in Justice League 2, or barring that, a movie after.”

After that, speculation has ranged from Martian Manhunter to Shazam. The last may actually be likely since Dwayne Johnson has reportedly been seen on set, and [is slated to play Black Adam](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Rock-Promises-Black-Adam-Showdown-With-Batman-Superman-69726.html) in the *Shazam* movie.

Answer (score -1):

The Green Lantern is the missing member of the Justice League. Take a look at the picture on this [Movie Pilot article](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2714000), which explains the true meaning of the term "Unite the Seven."

Comment: That article doesn't explain the meaning.

Answer (score -2):

No proof here, but I always assumed it meant the "seven seas". Since he is Aquaman and all, this made sense to me.

Comment: We do allow for speculative answers in the absence of canon, but we do ask for some minimal amount of explanation / justification. :)